# I want to upload file to HttpPostedFile which is present in "images" folder of my asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, httppostedfile

How to assign image present in "images" folder of my asp.net website to HttpPostedFile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpPostedFile is simply used by the ASP.NET FileUpload control by uploaded files only.

You can't assign a file to this class nor can you inherit from this class since it's sealed.

What you *can* do though, is create a similar class that has the following properties/functions:

```
public void SaveAs(string filename);

public string FileName { get; set; }

public string ContentType { get; set; }

public int ContentLength { get; set; }

public Stream InputStream { get; set; }
```